# Broken Samsung Galaxy S4 screen.. (not working) need little help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung

I have Samsung galaxy s4. I have broken screen which is not working and it's completely dark. Am I right that I need to change digitalizer and LCD screen ?

I am looking to buy from ebay co uk, which one would be the best the genuine or other brand ?

There is many videos on youtube, is it that hard to replace on my own, as I have to take out camera etc. Is there any safety tips what should I follow ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the replacement yourself, you're best to replace the entire front assembly. See the warnings as to why [on this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/pics-how-to-replace-glass-lcd-galaxy-s3-t2639359).

I would personally recommend the genuine item as I would have no idea where some other brand came from. I'd guess they would be refurbished items as these panels are made specifically for the devices. Using one might be a gamble, but I honestly don't know.

There are many safety tips, including having the right tools and ensuring you have grounded yourself. Prepare by watching the videos carefully, reading [other documentation](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Samsung+Galaxy+S4+Display+Assembly+Replacement/16540), and ensuring you know exactly what you will be doing. Don't force anything or the little bits will break. Ensure you have a lot of light in your work area, and that you have containers to put the little tiny screws and parts into.

My most important tip is to warn you that there's a reasonable chance you will damage the phone if this is your first try at fixing one. You need to balance that fact, as well as your own abilities, against the cost of having the fix done for you. I don't want to discourage you from trying it, but you need to be realistic about the possible outcomes.

Best of luck!